Creating a scroll event to change v-app-bar color from transparent to color
I am trying to create a transparent v-app-bar that is transparent at first but then as I scroll transitions to color. There is a similar post that is using options api and window.onscroll mounted as shown here:
How to Make Appbar Background Color Transparent in Vuetify
However,
I am trying to utilize composition api and also computed properties as this seems cleaner. I also am utilizing a scroll threshold for the hiding event so it is slightly different then this problem since I need this to all occur together. My issue is my code errors out and indicates "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')"
    <template>
    <div>
        <v-app-bar v-if="$vuetify.display.mdAndUp" class="px-md-4" :color="navBar.secondaryNavColor" scroll-behavior="hide" scroll-threshold="100" height="40" flat>
            <template #prepend>
                <v-btn color="primary" icon="mdi-facebook" variant="plain"/>
                <v-btn color="primary" icon="mdi-instagram" variant="plain"/>
            </template>
            <template #append>
                <v-btn class="ms-1 mx-5" color="primary" variant="plain" prepend-icon="mdi-account" rounded>Login</v-btn>
                <v-btn class="ms-1" color="primary" variant="plain" prepend-icon="mdi-upload" rounded>File Upload</v-btn>
            </template>
        </v-app-bar>
        <v-app-bar :elevation="5" class="px-md-4" :color="navBar.primaryNavColor" scroll-behavior="hide" scroll-threshold="100" height="100" flat>
            <template #prepend>
                    <v-app-bar-nav-icon
                    v-if="$vuetify.display.smAndDown"
                    @click="drawer = !drawer"
                    />
            </template>

            <v-spacer v-if="$vuetify.display.smAndDown"/>
            
            <v-img

                class="me-sm-8"
                max-width="240"
                min-width="200"
                src="/img/logo-header.png"
            />

            <v-spacer />

            <template v-if="$vuetify.display.mdAndUp">
                <v-btn
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                :active="i === 0"
                color="primary"
                class="me-2 text-none"
                v-bind="item"
                size="large"
                rounded
                />
            </template>
        </v-app-bar>

        <!-- <v-navigation-drawer
            v-if="$vuetify.display.smAndDown"
            v-model="drawer"
            location="top"
            temporary
            width="355"
            >
                <v-list class="py-0" slim>
                    <v-list-item link prepend-icon="mdi-home-outline" title="Dashboard" />

                    <v-list-group
                    prepend-icon="mdi-account-multiple-outline"
                    title="Customers"
                    >
                    <template #activator="{ props: activatorProps }">
                        <v-list-item v-bind="activatorProps" />
                    </template>

                    <v-list-item
                        link
                        prepend-icon="mdi-account-plus-outline"
                        title="Create New"
                    />

                    <v-list-group prepend-icon="mdi-magnify" title="Search">
                        <template #activator="{ props: activatorProps }">
                        <v-list-item v-bind="activatorProps" />
                        </template>

                        <v-list-item
                        link
                        prepend-icon="mdi-account-outline"
                        title="By Name"
                        />

                        <v-list-item
                        link
                        prepend-icon="mdi-email-outline"
                        title="By Email"
                        />

                        <v-list-item
                        link
                        prepend-icon="mdi-phone-outline"
                        title="By Phone"
                        />
                    </v-list-group>
                    </v-list-group>

                    <v-list-item link prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" title="Calendar" />

                    <v-list-item link prepend-icon="mdi-poll" title="Analytics" />

                    <v-divider />

                    <v-list-item link prepend-icon="mdi-inbox-outline" title="Inbox" />

                    <v-list-item
                    link
                    prepend-icon="mdi-bell-outline"
                    title="Notifications"
                    />

                    <v-divider />

                    <v-list-item
                    lines="two"
                    link
                    prepend-avatar="https://vuetifyjs.b-cdn.net/docs/images/avatars/planetary-subscriber.png"
                    subtitle="Vuetify Engineer"
                    title="John Leider"
                    />
                </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer> -->     
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { shallowRef, computed } from 'vue'
  
  const drawer = shallowRef(false)
  interface NavigationBarData {
    secondaryNavColor: string;
    primaryNavColor: string;
  }

  const navBar = computed<NavigationBarData>(
    () => {
      if (document.body.scrollTop < 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 100) {
        return {
          secondaryNavColor: 'transparent',
          primaryNavColor: 'transparent',
        }
      } else {
        return {
          secondaryNavColor: 'gray-lighten-3',
          primaryNavColor: 'surface',
        }
      }
    }
  )

  const items = [
    {
      text: 'Home',
    },
    {
      text: 'About',
    },
    {
      text: 'Services',
    },
    {
      text: 'Resources',
    },
    {
      text: 'Blog',
    },
    {
      text: 'Contact',
    }
  ]
</script>

